# Edittext: I want to popup window with list of items on click edittext

Tags: android

I want that when i click on edittext it should show a popup window on which there are radiobuttons with list of items and when i select an item it should show it in edittext. How to do it? I am not getting solution on it.Please tell anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
  }

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
  }

  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          textView.setText(which);
      }
    });
    builder.show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        //  at this u use alert box with radio buttons 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }


      @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        //leave blank
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
          //leave blank
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this also

```
      disValEdit.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {



                  } });
```